# Canon Powershot doesn't show up as a device in Picasa

Tags: google-picasa

I'm using 11.10 Desktop x64 and Picasa. I was using the latest stable Linux edition, and found that although my Canon Powershot was recognized and usable with the OS (and FSpot), Picasa wouldn't show it as a device from which pictures could be imported.

I've tried upgrading to Picasa 3.9 (using instructions on this forum), and the problem persists.

Any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your Canon Powershot device in Ubuntu (access like an external mass storage), you could acces to it in Picasa.

In the `Import From` field, try to select the "Folder" item and then choose the mounting point where you access your cam with Ubuntu, then you will be able to import your photos.

Comment: Good idea, but Picasa tries to launch the Wine-Windows file explorer, and hangs.